# Seeking a crawler in C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am looking for a working crawler sample code written in either c# or in Vb.net.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Crawler.aspx

Comment: who make a negative reading the code project sample is not working i have tried it a week before, before posting here

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Crawler.aspx

<sub>(Credits to [Mehrdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33708/mehrdad)). Will remove this answer if he posts his own.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try http://code.google.com/p/abot/

From its description...

Abot is an open source C# web crawler built for speed and flexibility. It takes care of the low level plumbing (multithreading, http requests, scheduling, link parsing, etc..). You just register for events to process the page data. You can also plugin your own implementations of core interfaces to take complete control over the crawl process.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://ncrawler.codeplex.com