# Generate Sitemap by URL using C#

Tags: c#, generator, sitemap

Good day. I need to write generator of Sitemap using C#. I have already written generator for local site where you input a path to your project (site) and my programm will find all web-pages in this directory and subdirectories, and will write them to the Sitemap file.

---

Now I need to do the same but for URL paths. All that I get to enter is a URL adress, and my programm have to found   all web-pages of this site and write them to the Sitemap. How can I organize such searching of pages? Or may be someone did something similiar? Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crawler in C# or in VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176979/crawler-in-c-sharp-or-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a web-crawler or a site-crawler. Essentially, what they do is get the source code of any website you want, strip all the excess html tags but not the hyperlink tags. This will leave a bunch of links that the program will use to 'crawl' onto more pages. Here is an outline of how it works: (I wont give any code, but I will go in-depth of how to make one)

A simple website:

```
<html>
<a href="www.somewebsite.com/link1.html">Link 1</a><br />
<a href="www.somewebsite.com/link2.html">Link 2</a><br />
<a href="www.somewebsite.com/link3.html">Link 3</a>
</html>
```

Our program will get the source code, but will remove all the useless tags, leaving:

```
<a href="www.somewebsite.com/link1.html">Link 1</a>
<a href="www.somewebsite.com/link2.html">Link 2</a>
<a href="www.somewebsite.com/link3.html">Link 3</a>
```

It will then just get the href="" attribute, leaving website urls:

```
www.somewebsite.com/link1.html
www.somewebsite.com/link2.html
www.somewebsite.com/link3.html
```

The program will then get the source code of each of those websites, doing the same thing over and over again. You can go even further and remove all links that use a GET request, ie:

```
www.somewebsite.com/link1?id=1
```

And ones containing links to other websites.

Once you have traveled to all the websites and got all the links, you can then store the information in a tree-like format, maybe in XML.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave me direction =)

Comment: I think you should accept this answer or you can add your own one and accept it